# Uncaught Error Function Name Must be a String, Log-in Form

Tags: php, html, authentication

As the title says im having a problem with a login form, im trying to make a simple one for a homework, however that error shows up after filling the forms and comparing them with the database, here is the form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log-in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
</div>

<form method="post" action="connect.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre de Usuario:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textInput"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contraseña:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" class="textInput"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="register_btn" class="Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the connection to the database:

```
    session_start();

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "registro";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("No hay conexion: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $username = $_POST('username');
    $password = $_POST('password');

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users where 
    username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($nr == 1){
        echo "Bienvenido: ".$nombre;
    }else if($nr == 0){
        echo "No Ingreso";
    }
?>
```

Honestly im a rookie at php and html, but im aware that the "$username" has to be a string in order to work, i tried using "strval" to convert it with no result.

edit: forgot to put the error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in connect.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in connect.php on line 15

Comment: please post the exact error text. usually php tells you the line where the error is

Comment: Sorry, forgot to:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in connect.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in connect.php on line 15"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Here !!!

// Replace and work

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: Hey Don't Feel @Francisco Javier Atondo Nubes